# Facebook login not working - Graph User is always null and Failure in SSL Library

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, https, poodle-attack

I have an application that has already been launched to the play store, Facebook login works fine, but the client has requested for changes. Changes have been made, now we are testing the application but Facebook login has stopped working. No explicit error message except for:

```
11-15 14:53:24.048: V/NativeCrypto(5777): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5de48ce8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

11-15 14:53:24.048: V/NativeCrypto(5777): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x623df485:0x00000000)

11-15 14:53:24.513: V/NativeCrypto(5777): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5d90cb08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

11-15 14:53:24.513: V/NativeCrypto(5777): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x623df485:0x00000000)

11-15 14:53:24.723: V/NativeCrypto(5777): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5de48ce8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

11-15 14:53:24.723: V/NativeCrypto(5777): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x623df485:0x00000000)

11-15 14:53:24.918: V/NativeCrypto(5777): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5d90cb08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

11-15 14:53:24.918: V/NativeCrypto(5777): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:762 0x623df485:0x00000000)
```

These error(s) occur after pressing the login button.

When the user is not logged in the LoginButton shows 'Log in with facebook' upon pressing and authenticating(with or without SSO), it will then display 'Log out' but Graph user is empty and I can't retrieve the username or display picture.

I am aware of this [post](https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10152444066278553):  and have already used the latest SDK from Facebook but nothing works.

**Here's my code** - I disabled SSO login but the problem still persist.

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

String pref_email = "";
// private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_EMAIL = "fb_email";
// private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "fb_name";
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private TextView userName;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private DiaryDAO diaries;
private Button uploadDbButton;
GraphUser globalGraphUser;
EditText feedbackEmailInput;
private Button syncDbButton;
private Button feedbackButton;
private Button exportSightingSD;

private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-54314298-1";
private Tracker tracker;
HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg:
                    // roll-up tracking.
    ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a
                        // company.
}

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics
                .getInstance(getActivity());
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics
                .newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics
                        .newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : analytics
                        .newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_try_fresh, container, false);

     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .permitAll().build();
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("sg.birdsofsingapore",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("" + e.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("" + e.toString());
    }


    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);

    userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i("fb login issue", "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if(session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i("gb login la", "Access Token " + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if(user != null) {
                            Log.i("gb login la", "User ID " + user.getId());
                            Log.i("gb login la", "Email " + user.asMap().get("email"));
                            userName.setText("Hi, " + user.getName());
                            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    authButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Log.d("session",session +"");

            if (user != null) {

                CallRestAPI.sendUsage("Fb Login Button Pressed",
                        getActivity());

                userName.setText("Hi, " + user.getName());
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                // userName.setText("[class]Hello, " + user.getName());

                globalGraphUser = user;

                System.out.println("output" + user.getName());

                diaries = new DiaryDAO(getActivity());

                if (diaries.updateDiaryOwner(user.asMap().get("email")
                        .toString())) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unable to update diary owners.");
                }

                diaries.close();

                FavouriteBirdDAO favouriteBirdDAO = new FavouriteBirdDAO(
                        getActivity());

                if (favouriteBirdDAO.updateFavouriteBirdOwner(user.asMap()
                        .get("email").toString())) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unable to update favourite owner.");
                }
                favouriteBirdDAO.close();

                SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.clear();
                e.commit();
                e.putString(PREF_EMAIL, "");
                e.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
                e.putString(PREF_EMAIL, user.asMap().get("email")
                        .toString());
                e.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, user.getName());
                e.apply();
                e.commit();

                CallRestAPI api = new CallRestAPI();
                api.login(getActivity());

                pref_email = mSharedPreferences.getString("fb_email", "");

            } else {


                System.out.println("USER IS NULL");

                profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
                userName.setText("You are not logged in.");

                if (mSharedPreferences != null) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.clear();
                    e.commit();
                    e.remove(PREF_EMAIL);
                    e.remove(PREF_USER_NAME);
                    pref_email = "";
                    e.commit();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    uploadDbButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.upload_sighting);
    uploadDbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sync.uploadLocalSightings(getActivity());

        }
    });

    // on click sync db, form JSON
    syncDbButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.update_bird_db);
    syncDbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CallRestAPI sync = new CallRestAPI();
            sync.syncDBird(getActivity());

        }
    });

    feedbackButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feedback_button);

    feedbackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CallRestAPI.sendUsage("Feedback Button Pressed", getActivity());

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            final View inflator = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.feedback_dialog, null);
            // builder.setView(inflator);

            builder.setTitle("Feedback");

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog
            // layout
            builder.setView(inflator);
            final EditText feedbackInput = (EditText) inflator
                    .findViewById(R.id.feedback_input);

            feedbackEmailInput = (EditText) inflator
                    .findViewById(R.id.feedback_email_input);
            if (globalGraphUser != null) {

                mSharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                        "prefs", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

                // Read the user's name,
                // or an empty string if nothing found
                String email = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_EMAIL, "");

                feedbackEmailInput.setText(email);
                feedbackEmailInput.setEnabled(false);

            }

            final Spinner frequency = (Spinner) inflator
                    .findViewById(R.id.feedback_spinner);

            // Add the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Submit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            int androidOS = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                            String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
                            String deviceBrand = android.os.Build.BRAND;
                            String deviceVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
                            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity()
                                    .getSystemService(
                                            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics();
                            int densityDpi = (int) (metrics.density * 160f);

                            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                            jsonObject.addProperty("frequency", frequency
                                    .getSelectedItem().toString());
                            jsonObject.addProperty("sdkVersion", androidOS);
                            jsonObject.addProperty("dpi", densityDpi);
                            jsonObject
                                    .addProperty("deviceName", deviceName);
                            jsonObject.addProperty("deviceBrand",
                                    deviceBrand);
                            jsonObject.addProperty("sdkVersion", androidOS);
                            jsonObject.addProperty("deviceOSVersion",
                                    deviceVersion);
                            jsonObject.addProperty(
                                    "deviceResolution",
                                    display.getHeight() + "x"
                                            + display.getWidth());
                            jsonObject.addProperty("feedback",
                                    feedbackInput.getText().toString());
                            jsonObject
                                    .addProperty("email",
                                            feedbackEmailInput.getText()
                                                    .toString());

                            CallRestAPI api = new CallRestAPI();

                            api.uploadFeedback(jsonObject, getActivity());

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                            CallRestAPI.sendUsage(
                                    "Feedback Cancel Button Pressed",
                                    getActivity());
                        }
                    });
            // Set other dialog properties

            // Create the AlertDialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    exportSightingSD = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.export_sighting);
    exportSightingSD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CallRestAPI.sendUsage("Export Sighting Button Pressed",
                    getActivity());

            SightingDAO sightingDAO = new SightingDAO(getActivity());
            FavouriteBirdDAO favouriteBirdDAO = new FavouriteBirdDAO(
                    getActivity());

            if (sightingDAO.getCountOfSightings() > 0) {

                if (sightingDAO.exportSightingDatabaseToCSV()) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Export sighting succesful! Please find your "
                                    + "export in Birds_Of_Singapore/user_data/sightings.csv."
                                    + "You can open this file using Microsoft Excel.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Export sightings unsuccesful. Please try uploading instead",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Sighting to export!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (favouriteBirdDAO.getCountOfFavouriteBirds() > 0) {

                if (favouriteBirdDAO.exportFavouritesDatabaseToCSV()) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Export favourite birds succesful! Please find your "
                                    + "export in Birds_Of_Singapore/user_data/favouriteBirds.csv."
                                    + "You can open this file using Microsoft Excel.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Export favourites unsuccesful. Please try uploading instead",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "No favourite birds to export!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            sightingDAO.close();
            favouriteBirdDAO.close();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();

    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);

    tracker = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    tracker.setScreenName("Settings Fragment");
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // logged in guy
            uploadDbButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            uploadDbButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (session.isClosed()) {
            pref_email = "";
            uploadDbButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            uploadDbButton.setEnabled(false);
            if (feedbackEmailInput != null) {
                feedbackEmailInput.setText("");
                feedbackEmailInput.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }

    // buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).reportActivityStart(
            getActivity());
    mSharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs",
            getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).reportActivityStop(
            getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


protected void onActivityResult(Context context, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

    default:
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
          break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("FB", "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("FB", "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);


        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // buttonsEnabled(true);
            // Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
               StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            // Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
            // {
            // @Override
            // public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // uploadDbButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // uploadDbButton.setEnabled(true);
            // }
            // });              

            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                    Log.e("user", "loged user");
                       // buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                    uploadDbButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    uploadDbButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();


        } else if (session.isClosed()) {
            // buttonsEnabled(false);
            // Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            e.clear();
            e.commit();
            uploadDbButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            uploadDbButton.setEnabled(false);
            pref_email = "";
            if (feedbackEmailInput != null) {
                feedbackEmailInput.setText("");
                feedbackEmailInput.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
};

}
```

Is there something in the SDK that I should change to prevent SSLv3 or force TLSv1?

Phones tested on: Note 2 stock ROM, Galaxy S4 Stock ROM, Samsung S3 4.2.2 CyanogenMod, Xiami Note ROM, Galaxy S2 stock ROM.

Phones that don't have the error: Note 3 stock ROM